# Is there a way to add a key Value Pair directly to all the Hashes in Nested HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap

I have nested HashMaps:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> nestedMap;
```

I want to execute `map.put("Hello","All")` on each HashMap in `nestedMap`.

Is there a way to do it without iterating over `nestedMap`?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible without iterating, be it explicit or implicit. It doesn't have to be complicated, though; just iterate over the collection returned by [`Map#values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29):

```
for(Map<String, String> map : nestedMap.values())
    map.put("Hello", "All");
```

In Java 8, you can also do this:

```
nestedMap.forEach((k,v) -> v.put("Hello", "All"));
```

Comment: Yes, just came to know today about Java Lambda Expressions : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 1):

No way that I am aware of because the value type of a Map is generic, meaning `Map` cannot expose a method like this because there is no guarantee the value is in fact a map.  In fact, more often than not, it is not a `Map`.

The good news however, is that with a foreach loop over a `Map.values()` call, the loop should be fairly simple.

```
for (Map<String, String> innerMap : nestedMap.values()) {
    innerMap.put("Hello", "All");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@arshajii is perfectly correct. But another thing to note is that if such global mappings are going to be common, then you might win by considering a design solution.  For the top level map implement global mappings explicitly. Something like this:

```
class MapWithGlobalPairs<Key, Value> extends HashMap<Key, Value> {
  private final HashMap<Key, Value> globalMap = new HashMap<>();

  public void putGlobal(Key key, Value val) {
    globalMap.put(key, val);
  }

  @Override
  public Value get(Key key) {
    Value val = globalMap.get(key);
    if (val == null)
      val = super.get(key);
    return val;
  }
}
```

This is untried code. I apologize in advance for silly errors.